# Having trouble aligning baselines of nav list elements that are css circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a nav out of css drawn circles as anchor elements. They all have varying amounts of text in them causing them to spill out of the circles. So I have used a JS solution to horizontally align the text to the middle of the circle. The problem I now have is that the circles baselines are unequal depending on how many lines of text are in them. Is there an easy css solution to this. Or will I have to calculate and amend the heights of each list item with javascript as well?

.html

```
<ul class="list-inline nav-horizontal">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab" class="stylish">#1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab" class="stylish">#2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#3" data-toggle="tab" class="stylish">#3</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#4" data-toggle="tab" class="stylish">#4</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#5" data-toggle="tab" class="stylish">#5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

.css

```
.list-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px; 
}

.stylish {
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 8px solid #ED1B24;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #BBAE92;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}

.stylish:hover, li.active .stylish {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #ED1B24;
}
```

.js

```
$("a.stylish").contents().wrap("<span>");
$("a.stylish span").css({
    position : "relative",
    "top" : function() {
        return ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. If css will work I am fine with that

Comment: I answered, dont you mind to post us some link to see live demo and help you with implementation?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a live example. just working on it locally

Answer (score 0):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/hd8donbn/3/

```
.nav-horizontal li:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%
}

.stylish {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ED1B24;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 90%
}
```

If its ok i will explain everything :D

Comment: this works ok if all the text will fit on one line. However I have a responsive design and on screen size change the text wraps to the next line causing the shift in baselines

Comment: Do you want to stay them every time inline? even with scrollbars?

Comment: no. the circles will move down to next line when width of page gets smaller

Comment: just figured a simple solution... added `vertical-align:text-top;` to the `.list-inline li`

Comment: -.-" be more clear next time :D ... and paste all the code because here http://jsfiddle.net/hd8donbn/5/ nothing seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple css solution. Adding `vertical-align:text-top;` to the class of `.list-inline li` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

well, not to be rude here, but i've written a markup of my own to cater to you needs, disregarding what you've given in your question. Hope you find it usefull:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">medium content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a bit larger content</a><`enter code here`/li>
    <li><a href="#">really large hunk of content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">this is a rrrrreeeeaaaalllllllyyyyy big chunk, with a long word too</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

css

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none; /*remove markers for `li`*/
    }

    li {
        border-radius: 50%; /*border-radius 70px;*/
        overflow: hidden; /*hide overflowing text, if any*/
        float: left; /*puts things in line, with their tops aligned. */
        /*If `display:inline-block` is used, it will match the bottoms at same level. try it*/

        border: 8px solid #ED1B24;
        display: block;
        height: 140px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 140px;
    }
    li a{
        padding: 0 5px; /*prevent border cutting*/
        word-wrap: break-word; /*breaks long words*/
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #BBAE92;

        /*the next 4 allow a child to be centered vertically*/
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);

    }
    li.active,
    li:hover{
        cursor: pointer; /*makes it look like a link*/
        background: #ED1B24;
    }
    li.active a,
    li:hover a{
        color: #fff;
    }
```

---

and some minor js

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).child('a').click();
});
```